# Show that $\sinh(z)$ where $z = x + iy$ is analytic in the whole complex plane

Tags: complex-analysis

How would I show that $\sinh(z)$ is analytic in the whole complex plane? Would I separate $\sinh(z)$ into exponentials or use that $\sinh(x+iy) = \sinh(x)\cosh(iy) + \cosh(x)\sinh(y)$?

Comment: What definition of $\sinh$ are you working with? And what definition of "analytic"?

Answer (score 4):

[Analytic is a function that is locally given by a convergent power series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analytic_function). So, if you have $$\sinh z = \frac{1}{2}(e^z-e^{-z}),$$
and the exponential has an everywhere convergent power series $$e^z=\sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{z^n}{n!},$$ so the hyperbolic sine is analytic on the whole plane:
$$\sinh z = \frac12\left(\sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{z^n}{n!}-\sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-z)^n}{n!}\right)=\sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{z^{2n+1}}{(2n+1)!}$$

Answer (score 3):

Verify that your definition of $\sinh$ gives $\sinh z=\frac {e^{z}-e^{-z}} 2$. Since $e^{z}$ is analytic in the whole complex plane so is $\sinh z$.